# React Router 6 relative attribute's meaning of Link element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React Router 6.4+ (specifically, 6.22.1) and having the following route config:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: '/',
    element: <RootLayout />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <HomePage /> },
      { path: 'events', element: <EventsPage/> },
      { path: 'events/:eventId', element: <EventDetailPage /> },
      { path: 'events/new', element: <NewEventPage /> },
      { path: 'events/:eventId/edit', element: <EditEventPage /> }
    ]
  }
])

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router}/>;
}
```

My `EventsPage` component is:

```
const DUMMY_EVENTS = [
  {
    id: 'e1',
    title: 'Some events'
  },
  {
    id: 'e2',
    title: 'Another event'
  }
];

function EventsPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Events Page</h1>
      <ul>
        {DUMMY_EVENTS.map(event => <li key={event.id}>
          <Link to={event.id}>{event.title}</Link>
        </li>)}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default EventsPage;
```

Clicking on each event will lead to the `EventDetailPage` component:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function EventDetailPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>EventDetailPage</h1>
      <Link
        to='..'
        // relative='path'
      >
        Back
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}

export default EventDetailPage;
```

Now if we reference to the official documentation here https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link#relative the behavior of navigating relative path is inconsistent between going "forward" and "backward":

- Clicking on each event in the EventsPage (relative='route' by default) means we should go forward relative the route hierarchy. But it's not. It actually navigates to the route of EventDetailPage, which gives me a perception that it is "path relative". And if the behavior is correctly "route hierarchy relative", then where should it navigate to?
- Clicking on the back link will correctly navigate back up on route level (relative='route') to the root layout, which renders the HomePage as the index route. It will only navigate back up on path segment if I uncomment the relative attribute in EventDetailPage component.

So what I'm looking for is a correct explanation for the relative attribute of Link component here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Clicking on each event in the EventsPage (relative='route' by default)
> means we should go forward relative the route hierarchy. But it's not.
> It actually navigates to the route of EventDetailPage, which gives me
> a perception that it is "path relative". And if the behavior is
> correctly "route hierarchy relative", then where should it navigate
> to?

When on `"/events"` and using a *relative* link target, i.e. `"e1"` and `"e2"`, this is the same as using `"./e1"` and `"./e2"` where the `"."` represents the current route (*if using `relative="route"`*) or the current path (*if using `relative="path"`*) and the result is that you are correctly navigated from `"/events"` to `"/events/:eventId"`.

Similarly, if you instead used `"../e1"` or `"../e2"` link targets the `".."` refers to the parent `Route` or path, which is `RootLayout` for `relative="route"` and `"/"` for `relative="path"`, and the result would be navigation to `"/e1"` or `"/e2"`.

> Clicking on the back link will correctly navigate back up on route
> level (relative='route') to the root layout, which renders the
> HomePage as the index route. It will only navigate back up on path
> segment if I uncomment the relative attribute in EventDetailPage
> component.
>
> So what I'm looking for is a correct explanation for the relative
> attribute of Link component here.

I think the docs explain it correctly enough and also include a good code example with comments.

[Link::relative](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link#relative)

> By default, links are relative to the route hierarchy
> (relative="route"), so .. will go up one Route level from the current
> contextual route. Occasionally, you may find that you have matching
> URL patterns that do not make sense to be nested, and you'd prefer to
> use relative path routing from the current contextual route path. You
> can opt into this behavior with relative="path":
>
> ```
> // Contact and EditContact do not share additional UI layout
> <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
>   <Route path="contacts/:id" element={<Contact />} />
>   <Route
>     path="contacts/:id/edit"
>     element={<EditContact />}
>   />
> </Route>;
>
> function EditContact() {
>   // Since Contact is not a parent of EditContact we need to go up one level
>   // in the current contextual route path, instead of one level in the Route
>   // hierarchy
>   return (
>     <Link to=".." relative="path">
>       Cancel
>     </Link>
>   );
> }
> ```

The basic gist is that normally link navigation *does* occur *relative* to the ***routing structure***, e.g. from one `Route` to another `Route`, but that sometimes you don't want this behavior, such as in the above example and in your code where you would prefer to use the ***path structure***, e.g. to navigate from one path to another path.

### `relative="route"`

A regular `<Link to="..">Back</Link>` will navigate ***up*** the routing tree to `{ path: "events", element: <EventsPage /> },`'s parent route, e.g. back to `"/"` and render the `RootLayout` component.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { // <-- (2) to this route
    path: "/",
    element: <RootLayout />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <HomePage /> },
      { path: "events", element: <EventsPage /> },
      { // <-- (1) from this route
        path: "events/:eventId",
        element: <EventDetailPage />
      },
      { path: 'events/new', element: <NewEventPage /> },
      { path: 'events/:eventId/edit', element: <EditEventPage /> }
    ]
  }
]);
```

### `relative="path"`

A `<Link to=".." relative="path">Back</Link>` will navigate ***up*** a path segment, e.g. from `"/events/123"` to `"/events"`.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <RootLayout />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <HomePage /> },
      {
        path: "events", // <-- (2) to this path
        element: <EventsPage />
      },
      {
        path: "events/:eventId", // <-- (1) from this path
        element: <EventDetailPage />
      },
      { path: 'events/new', element: <NewEventPage /> },
      { path: 'events/:eventId/edit', element: <EditEventPage /> }
    ]
  }
]);
```